# Does AWS RDS Multi AZ in conjuction with read replicas have less replication lag than just read replicas?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Quoting the AWS docs:

"You can use Multi-AZ deployments and Read Replicas in conjunction to enjoy the complementary benefits of each. You can simply specify that a given Multi-AZ deployment is the source DB Instance for your Read Replicas."

Does a Multi-AZ read replica have less replication lag than ordinary read replicas? I ask because for Multi-AZ it states: "it synchronously replicates the data".

Also:

"Multi-AZ deployments utilize synchronous replication, making database writes **concurrently** on both the primary and standby so that the standby will be up-to-date in the event a failover occurs. While our technological implementation for Multi-AZ DB Instances maximizes data durability in failure scenarios, it precludes the standby from being accessed directly or used for read operations. The fault tolerance offered by Multi-AZ deployments make them a natural fit for production environments; to learn more about Multi-AZ deployments, please visit this FAQ section."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-AZ RDS establishes a Secondary replica of the DB in a different AZ and is replicated synchronously. It can only be accessed when promoted to being the Master DB instance and is used exclusively for disaster recovery.

Read Replicas are an asynchronous replication of the Master DB instance and can be created in one or more AZs/Regions.

The two features operate independently of each other. Secondary RDS instances are not used as a source for RR's therefore any RR lag will be constant regardless of the RDS availability configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link or quote for the Secondary replica can't be used as a source for the Read Replica? I've looked everywhere in the documentation, faqs etc and can't see it noted. That's a shame if true because that means read replicas will suffer from lag which isn't acceptable to me, especially as the documentation says several minutes of lag should be tolerated (what if someone makes a post and then it's not visible on the read replica for 30 seconds...)

Comment: @HardWorker *precludes the standby from being accessed directly or used for read operations* should be sufficient confirmation.  There is no such thing as a synchronous read replica in RDS for MySQL.  Are you familiar with MySQL asynchronous replication?  On properly-sized hardware (replica server identical to, or larger than, the master) the *typical* latency is milliseconds, and you can always *ask* a replica how far behind it is.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot On aws, what is the typical read replica lag? In the documentation it refers to 5 minutes lag as "small":  _"If an existing Read Replica has fallen too far behind to meet your requirements, you can delete it and create a new one with the same endpoint by using the same DB Instance Identifier and Source DB Instance Identifier as the deleted Read Replica. Keep in mind that the re-creation process will be counter-productive at small lag levels (e.g under five minutes of lag), and should be used with prudence (i.e. only when the Read Replica is significantly behind)"_

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Do you think a good approach then would be aways to check how far the replica is behind before doing a read from it? And if it's more than 1 second behind, do a read from the master? I'm curious how people can use these read replicas effectively in most case scenarios I need e.g. someone posting a forum topic and then returning to the forum and not seeing the forum topic because the read replica is lagging